# final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, mysql, linker

I am using these library in my project

- [Crow Framework](https://github.com/ipkn/crow)
- [SQLPP11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11)
- [SQLPP-Connector-MySQL](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql)
- [Howard Hinnant's Date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)
- [json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11)

and compiling my project using

```
g++ -std=c++1y -I ../../date main.cpp -lpthread -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_system -ljson11
```

And everyday was running completely fine till yesterday. But now i am getting 
this error,

```
┌─[shravan40@Debian] - [~/Work/algorithm] - [Fri Nov 18, 18:33]
└─[$] <git:(riskProfiling*)> g++ -std=c++1y -I ../../date main.cpp -lpthread -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_system -ljson11
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libsqlpp-mysql.a(connection.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libsqlpp-mysql.a(prepared_statement.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libsqlpp-mysql.a(char_result.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libsqlpp-mysql.a(bind_result.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libsqlpp-mysql.a(connection_handle.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
┌─[shravan40@Debian] - [~/Work/algorithm] - [Fri Nov 18, 18:53]
└─[$] <git:(riskProfiling*)>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use -fPIC option as shown, I guess?

Comment: Might have something to do with the json11 helper functions, some of which are static. Additionally, it may be related to the way json11 treats numbers, as indicated in the `json11.hpp` file.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521859/nonrepresentable-section-on-output-error-during-linking-on-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, i have figured out the solution.

It was the problem with `g++` version. Recent versions `g++-5` and `g++-6` have such problems, But when i get back to old `g++` version `4.9.2` everything is running smooth.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I had this problem after upgrading to Ubuntu version 17. Compiling with -fPIC did not help. Did you ever find a way to fix this without using an older g++ version?

Comment: @JesseBusman : No, I didn't find any. But library author claims that it's work on his machine. So I think, we need to figure out this by ourself.

Comment: @Shravan40 I just ran into this with my own project, which was building fine with Ubuntu 16. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and now am getting this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS; but for me it was easily solved by running "make clean" and rebuilding the project. This might not work for everyone, but it is so simple that it seems likely that it is worth a try as a first resort for anyone who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS with gtest/gmock library. Solution is you need recompile your libraries which you use in project with currently compiler.