# Suggestions to compile the program fung-calc

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Im trying to compile the program called fungcalc, its a graph software which the last version was made on 2003, it was designed to run in kde 3.5 (qt3).

Now the steps that I did was to install the qt3 libs, and the required componens missing based in the

```
./configure  --disable-kde-app
```

this argument remove the support for kde (and the need for its libs too). 
When compiling it stops almost at the end (since many .so where compiled but not the main executable)with the next output

```
/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:412: libfungcalc.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/fung-calc-1.3.2b/src/libfungcalc'
```

With the same error for the lines 277,337,495,505 of the Makefile.

So what suggestion  could be so I can start to roam the entire code?

The entire Makefile is [here](https://pastebin.com/66MHJtAE)

I don't know if this runs on 64 bits (but I suppose it does).

Comment: I did [google "nonrepresentable section on output"](https://www.google.com/search?q=nonrepresentable+section+on+output) (out of curiosity) and found e.g. [SO: “Nonrepresentable section on output” error during linking on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003485/7478597).

Comment: And btw. _When compiling it stops almost at the end (since many .so where compiled but not the main executable)_ It quite clear says the it failed to build `libfungcalc.la` - sounds rather like a library but not like the executable as assumed by you.

Comment: @Scheff, Im not aware of how many files left without compile, the idea is to note that the executable was not build, rather that it was the only one without compile

Comment: @Scheff, thanks for the article and the help